# Checkbox to run only after the main macro is run

Tags: excel, vba

I have a main form (I guess I could call it so), that exports Excel sheets to PDFs. I want to have a checkbox that allows users to open the PDF file after run if it's checked. At the moment, when the checkbox is clicked, it tries to run the checkbox macro, but if it's not checked, it returns an error. This is the code:

```
Sub CheckBox5_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim chckBox As CheckBox
    Set chckBox = Sheets("CompileSheet").CheckBoxes("CheckBox5")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    If chckBox.Value = 1 Then
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
    Else
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    End If
End Sub
```

Don't hesitate to ask for clarification.
Thanks.

Comment: Don’t attach this code to the checkbox.  Rather have the routine that normally creates the PDF look at the checkbox when it runs.  Just let the checkbox be a passive switch that gets checked by other code.

Comment: `Set ws = ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet2")` There is no Sheet2 until the main macro makes it.

Comment: I'll see if I can figure taht out. Thank you @RbarryYoung

Comment: How would I make the checkbox a passive? would I use `Application.Caller`?

Comment: How are you currently executing the code that exports to PDF?

Comment: All I'm dong is after a bunch of other sheets are put on one sheet, it exports that sheet if that makes sense.

Comment: @kaligirl "passive" just means that there's no event attached to it.  Nothing happens when you click it, it just changes it's own state and your code checks it later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!

I had to leave the checkbox macro blank(I didn't know you could) and figured out how to find the name if the box, and the following code after the sheet is created works for me:

```
If xlBook.Sheets("CompileSheet").Shapes("Check Box 5").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
Else
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
End If
```

Thank you everyone for the help!